# Determine $k$ in PDF.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ random variables with PDF given by
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{aligned}kxy, \quad x\geq 0, y\geq 0, x+y\leq 1\\ 0, \quad \text{elsewhere} \end{aligned} \right.
> \end{eqnarray*}
> $1.$ Calculate $k$.
> $2.$ Calculate the marginals density of $X$ and $Y$.
> $3.$ Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?
> $4.$ Calculate $$\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y), \quad \mathbb{P}(X\geq 1/2 | X+Y\leq 3/4), \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{P}(X^{2}+Y^{2}\leq 1)$$
> $5.$ Calcule the joint density function of $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$ with their respective marginals.

**My approach:**

1. Since that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)=1 \implies \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}kxydydx=1 \implies k=24.$$
2. By definition, we have that $$f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{1-x}24xydy=12x(x-1)^{2}, \quad x\in [0,1]$$and $$f_{Y}(y)=\int_{0}^{1-y}24xydx=12y(y-1)^{2}, \quad y \in [0,1]$$
3. Since that $$f(x,y)\not=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$$so $X$ and $Y$ are not independents.
4. **Now, here I'm problem in how can I calculate $\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1/2| X+Y\leq 3/4)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X^{2}+Y^{2}\leq 1)$** *Can you help me here?*. I could find that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq Y)=1/2$.
5. *Here, I don't know how can I solve this part. I was trying to apply the Jacobian transformation, but I don't know how to use this method well. So, I'm not getting a good solution focus.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $k=24$, and the marginals are as you calculated: $f_{\small X}(x)=12x(1-x)^2\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}$ and $f_{\small Y}(x)=f_{\small X}(x)$ by symmetry.

Also by symmetry, $\Bbb P(X\leq Y)=\Bbb P(X\geq Y)$, so (since $\Bbb P(X=Y)=0)$ then $\Bbb P(X\geq Y)=1/2$.

---

Then you just need to use the definition of conditional probability:$$\begin{align}\Bbb P(X\geq 1/2\mid X+Y\leq 3/4)&=\dfrac{\Bbb P(1/2\leq X, X+Y\leq 3/4)}{\Bbb P(X+Y\leq 3/4)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\Bbb P(1/2\leq X\leq 3/4-Y)}{\Bbb P(X\leq 3/4-Y)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^{1/4}\int_{1/2}^{3/4-y}24xy\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y}{\displaystyle\int_0^{3/4}\int_0^{3/4-y}24 xy\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y}\end{align}$$

For the next problem, notice that for $0\leq x\leq 1$ that $1-x\leq \surd(1-x^2)$

---

We have $U=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$, so $U+V=2X$ and $U-V=2Y$.

Thus the Jacobian matrix is: $$\begin{align}\mathsf J_{\small U,V}^{\small X,Y}(u,v)&=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial (u+v)/2}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial (u+v)/2}{\partial v}\\\dfrac{\partial (u-v)/2}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial (u-v)/2}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&-1/2\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$
Now just apply the Jacobian Transformation: $$ f_{\small U,V}(u,v)=\lVert\mathsf J_{\small U,V}^{\small X,Y}(u,v)\rVert\, f_{\small X,Y}\left(\tfrac {u+v}{2},\tfrac {u-v}2\right)$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Very good explanation. Thank you! However, I have a question, can you explain a little more why $\mathbb{P}(X^{2}+Y^{2}\leq 1)$? I'm not seeing your suggestion clear...I'm sure I can find the marginals of the joint density.

Comment: I'm solving the last part and I could find $f_{U,V}(u,v)=3(u^{2}-v^{2})$ with $-u\leq v \leq u \leq 1$ and $f_{U}(u)=4u^{3}\textbf{1}_{\{ 0\leq u \leq 1\}}$ and $f_{V}(v)=1-3v^{2}+2|v^{3}|\textbf{1}_{\{ -1\leq v \leq 1\}}$. Is it correct?

Comment: I understand! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I have a question, can you explain a little more why $\mathbb{P}(X^{2}+Y^{2}\leq 1)$

Considering that, by assumption of the exercise

$$\mathbb{P}(X,Y \in A)=1$$

I think that the answer is self evident looking at the following drawing

[image]

Comment: You're right!. I was so busy thinking about the algebraic part of the suggestion that I omitted the obvious geometric part. Thank you!

Comment: +1,upvote for your clarification.